# Почему EF core не может сравнить DateTimeOffse?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

`((a.DateOfRecive == null || b.DateOfRecive == null) || a.DateOfRecive.Value.Month == DateTimeOffset.Now.Month)`
или 
`((a.DateOfRecive == null || b.DateOfRecive == null) || a.DateOfRecive.Value.Month == b.DateOfRecive.Value.Month)`
 кидают такую ошибку при попытке отсортировать Where

```
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

EF core 3.1

Comment: Из статьи, ссылка на которую имеется в описании ошибки:
"Если проекцию верхнего уровня в запросе невозможно преобразовать на стороне сервера, EF Core получает необходимые данные с сервера и вычисляет оставшиеся части запроса на стороне клиента. Если EF Core обнаруживает выражение в любом месте, кроме проекции верхнего уровня, которую невозможно преобразовать на стороне сервера, то возникает исключение времени выполнения." Т.е. не может преобразовать тип на стороне сервера и предлагает Вам "материализовать" набор данных и произвести обработку на стороне клиента.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings поэтому, скорее всего, ещё не будет поддерживать Time.

Comment: Есть предложения как организовать вычисления на сервере БД. выносить сортировку в бизнес логику не очень хочется.

Comment: Вы утверждаете или спрашиваете?

Comment: Спрашиваю совета..

Comment: `Есть предложения как организовать вычисления на сервере БД.` - использовать хранимые процедуры.